# Factoring $2 + \frac{4}{2Z + 1} - \frac{3}{Z} + \frac{Z}{2Z^2 - Z}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

How to factor below expression please?
$$2 + \frac{4}{2Z + 1} - \frac{3}{Z} + \frac{Z}{2Z^2 - Z}$$

What I got is
$$\frac{8Z^3 - 2Z^2 - 5Z + 3}{Z(4Z^2 - 1)}$$
but I was told the answer doesn't look like that. Not sure if it can further simplified.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Your answer is certainly equivalent to the original. Multiplying $(2Z+1)(2Z-1)$ to get $(4Z^2-1)$ is the opposite of factoring, though. ;)  It seems a little weird to me that the numerator doesn't factor. (*Mathematica* confirms that it doesn't.) Are you sure you've stated the problem correctly?

Comment: Thank you for checking it! We double checked there is no typo. So, I asked the student to share the answer with me once her teacher post it. Maybe it's a bad problem. Thanks again!